# EmberJS application - structure and more

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, ember.js

During the preparation for the large project, I am investigating some JS MV* frameworks that will be used by team with about 10 developers.
First I tried AngularJS, since it looks like it's performance the best of all frameworks ([SO topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11458436/angular-js-backbone-js-or-which-has-better-performance)). It has some nice futures like DI, but I don't really liked to work with it, since for me it little bit messy code that hard to understand and I like the code to be clean as mach as possible, well structured and easy to read.

Currently I'm trying EmberJS and it looks like ember, very developer friendly and it's easy to work with it. So I wrote a small "log in widget" to see how ember app should be structured. During the development I tried to solve some issues like async requests, animations, etc...

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VwgpV/1/)

The "widget" already work and does everything that I wanted him to do, but at this point, I still have some questions and I would like to hear some advice from experienced ember developers regarding the current code structure, object roles, and issues that I can meet later when using ember.

So here some questions that I have:

1) Ember views are cool, but what if I want ember to handle existing elements actions and animation? I mean for example I have link rendered on server (or HTML received with AJAX), how I can bind ember action to handle it's click action and instantiate my custom LinkView for it? I'm sure I can find solution by "manually" binding to DOM event with jQuery or something, but does exists the "Ember" way to do it?

2) Is it possible to set `StateManager` properties, before it entering initial state, but without setting it on Class level?

3) Can someone point me to example of how to use `Em.Deffered`? I made promises work with jQuery `$.Deferred()`, but I would like not to have dependency on jQuery in my `StateManager`.

4) Does exists other "Ember" way to tell framework to add view to DOM in already hidden state? I tried to set isVisible: false, but it not works.

5) Does exists other way then add hidden view again, to workaround error "Cannot perform operations on a Metamorph that is not in the DOM."?

Here is source for reference:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="GuestView">
        User: {{view Ember.TextField valueBinding='controller.username' placeholderBinding='controller.usernameHint'}}
        Pass: {{view Ember.TextField valueBinding='controller.password' placeholderBinding='controller.passwordHint' }}
        <br/>
        <button {{action login this}}>Login</button>
    </script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="UserView">
        Hello {{ username }}
        <button {{action logout this}}>Logout</button>
    </script>

<script type="text/javascript">
        var App = Em.Application.create({
            authController: null,
            currentUserBinding: 'authController.content',

            ready: function () {
                this.set("authController", App.AuthController.create());
            }
        });

        App.AuthController = Em.ObjectController.extend({
            content: null,
            target: null,
            init: function () {
                this.set("content", this.getUserFromCookieOrDefault());

                //Is it possible in Ember, to set the controller before entering initial state,
                //but without setting it on Class level?
                this.set("target", App.AuthManager.reopen({ controller: this }).create({
                    //initialState: this.get("content").isAuthorized ? "authorized" : "guest"
                }));
                this.get("target").transitionTo(this.get("content").isAuthorized ? "authorized" : "guest");
            },

            doLogin: function (mgr, context) {
                console.log("logging in");

                //Validation, etc...
                //Imulating async Data loading, actually, it should be done with promises
                setTimeout(function () { mgr.transitionTo("authorized"); }, 1000);
            },

            doLogout: function (mgr, context) {
                console.log("logging out");

                //logout logic
                mgr.transitionTo("guest");
                this.set("content", App.Guest.create());
            },

            getUserFromCookieOrDefault: function () {
                return App.Guest.create();
                //return App.User.create({ username: "TestUser" });
            },
        });

        App.AuthManager = Em.StateManager.extend({
            controller: null,
            canTransist: true,

            // { data, commitCallback, abortCallback } 
            transitionTo: function (path, context) {
                var originalTransitionTo = this._super,
                    manager = this,
                    canTransist = "canTransist",
                    deffered = null,
                    originalTransitionToParams = context && (context.data || context.commitCallback || context.abortCallback) ?
                                                 context.data : context;

                if (!manager.get(canTransist)) {
                    Em.assert("Already in Transition");
                    return;
                }

                manager.set(canTransist, false);

                if (!manager.currentState) {
                    originalTransitionTo.apply(manager, [path, originalTransitionToParams]);
                    manager.set(canTransist, true);
                    return;
                }

                if (!manager.currentState.isAsyncExit) {
                    originalTransitionTo.apply(manager, [path, originalTransitionToParams]);
                    manager.set(canTransist, true);
                }
                else {

                    //How to use Em.Deffered?
                    deffered = $.Deferred();
                    deffered.done(commitTransition).fail(abortTransition);
                    manager.currentState.beforeExit(deffered, originalTransitionToParams);
                }

                function commitTransition() {
                    originalTransitionTo.apply(manager, [path, originalTransitionToParams]);
                    manager.set(canTransist, true);
                }

                function abortTransition() {
                    manager.set(canTransist, true);
                }
            },

            states: {
                guest: Em.State.create({
                    isAsyncExit: true,

                    enter: function (mgr) {
                        console.log("guest");

                        App.guestView = App.GuestView.create({
                            templateName: "GuestView",
                            controller: mgr.controller,
                        }).append();
                    },

                    beforeExit: function (promise, context) {
                        App.guestView.remove(promise);
                    },

                    login: function (mgr, context) {
                        mgr.controller.doLogin(mgr, context);
                    }
                }),

                authorized: Em.State.create({
                    isAsyncExit: true,

                    enter: function (mgr) {
                        console.log("authorized");

                        App.userView = App.UserView.create({
                            templateName: "UserView",
                            controller: mgr.controller,
                        }).append();
                    },

                    beforeExit: function (promise) {
                        App.userView.remove(promise);
                    },

                    logout: function (mgr, context) {
                        mgr.controller.doLogout(mgr, context);
                    }
                })
            }
        });

        App.FadingView = Em.View.extend({
            //Does exists other "Ember" way to tell framework to add view to DOM in already hidden state?
            //I tried to set isVisible: false, but it not works
            classNames: ['initialHidden'],

            didInsertElement: function () {

                //If using this.$().hide().show('slow') without 'initialHidden' class then view is still visible when alert shown
                //alert("View visible");
                this.$().hide().fadeIn(500).removeClass("initialHidden");

            },

            remove: function (promise) {

                var originalView = this,
                    originalViewElement = originalView.$(),
                    clonedView = originalView.$().clone(),
                    originalRemove = this._super;

                $(clonedView).attr("id", $(clonedView).attr("id") + "_clone").removeClass('ember-view');
                $("*", clonedView).removeClass('ember-view').remove("script[id^=metamorph]");
                originalView.$().replaceWith(clonedView);

                //This line exists, only because of Metamorph error:
                //Cannot perform operations on a Metamorph that is not in the DOM.
                $(originalViewElement).css("display", "none").appendTo("body");

                clonedView.fadeOut(1000, function () {
                    $(this).remove();
                    originalRemove.apply(originalView);
                    promise.resolve();
                });

            }
        });

        App.GuestView = App.FadingView.extend();
        App.UserView = App.FadingView.extend();

        App.User = Em.Object.extend({
            username: "",
            isAuthorized: true
        });

        App.Guest = Em.Object.extend({
            isAuthorized: false,
            password: "",
            usernameHint: "Username...",
            passwordHint: "Password..."
        });
    </script>
```